Rainbow line in gnuplot (?)
I want to have a single line on the plot, that changes colors in given range.
I tried something like this:
set palette defined (0.0 '#01748D', 0.1 '#22D6CC', 0.2 '#68DEFF', 0.3 '#2E5DD1', \
                     0.4 '#2E5DD1', 0.5 '#611EBA', 0.6 '#9349DF', 0.7 '#611EBA', \
                     0.8 '#BF1E90', 0.9 '#FA6FD3')
set cbrange [100:350]
set colorbox horiz user origin 0.22,0.65 size 0.335,0.04
set cbtics 100 offset 0,2.3
set format cb '\scriptsize{$%1.0f$}'
set palette maxcolor 40

set style data lines
plot 'dane.dat' using 1:2:(($1-100)/(350-100)) with lines lc palette lw 3 notitle

but it didn't work.
I tried ChatGPT tricks, but nothing worked, so at this point I think it's impossible. But some of you are smarter, so please, let me know!

What does "didn't work" mean? How does your data look like? What is the x-range of your data? How does your output graph look like and how should it look like? Check this: minimal repdroducible example

Are you sure you have that color range correctly set?  What if you try set cbrange [*:*]?

You are on the right track.  I am guessing that you are not setting the cbrange correctly to match the actual 3rd column values.  Here is a simple example the uses plot '+' to dummy up a data file consisting of 100 evenly space data points between 1 and 10.
set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10
set sample 100
set xrange [0:10]
plot '+' using ($1) : (sin($1)/$1) : ($1) with lines lw 3 lc palette notitle



Thank you! But can you explain, what plot '+' means? I don't get it

@Lilla_mu check help special-filenames.

I don't have your data file to use as input so I used the special filename  +, which generates one data point per sample.  You would of course replace that with your actual file name.
